# Is the spectral norm submultiplicative?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

I wonder if the $2$-norm or spectral norm is also submultiplicative for non-square matrices, i.e.,

$$\|  A B \|_2 \leq \| A \|_2 \cdot \| B \|_2$$

if the number of columns of $A$ coincides with the number of rows of $B$. In the literature I can only find a statement about square matrices. Thanks a lot for any remarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that if $A$ is $m\times n$ then $||A||_2$ is the norm of $A$ as a map from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$, where both spaces have the Euclidean norm? If so then this is obvious; it's trivial that operator norms are submultiplicative: $$||STx||\le||S||\,||Tx||\le||S||\,||T||\,||x||,$$so $||ST||\le||S||\,||T||$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, The usual definition: $\lVert A \rVert_2=\sqrt{\rho(A^{\top}A)}$ applies to non-square matrices too in my opinion, doesnt it?

Comment: $\rho$ is the largest absolute eigenvalue

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Why is it trivial that operator norms are submultiplicative? Based on the following, we can not get $\|ST\|\le \|S\|\|T\|$. 
$$\|S(Tx)\|\le \|S\|\|Tx\|\le\|S\|\|T\|\|x\|,$$ $$\|(ST)x\|\le \|ST\|\|x\|$$

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435621/show-that-the-operator-norm-is-submultiplicative).

Comment: @suineg What??? If $T$ is linear and $c>0$ then it's clear from the definition that $||Tx||\le c||x||$ isequivalent to $||T||\le c$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I still can not get $\|ST\|\le \|S\|\|T\|$ from your argument. From the words ''clear''''obvious'', I think you take everything granted. Can you make your argument convincing with mathematical words, not the other way around?

Comment: There's nothing I could be taking for granted here - everything is immediate from the definitions.  Tell me what version of the definition of $||T||$ you want to use. And tell me which half you're having trouble with:(i)Lemma: $||Tx||\le c||x|$ for all $x$ if and only if $||t||\le c$, (ii) it follows from the lemma that $||ST||\le||S||\,||T||$.