# Sub-multiplicative property of matrix norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I just wanted to clarify my understanding of the sub-multiplicative property of the matrix operator norm.

---

On [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Properties) it says for any matrix:

$
\|AB\|_{\alpha, \gamma} \leq \|A\|_{\beta, \gamma} \|B\|_{\alpha,\beta}
$

But then says for square matrices:

$\|AB\|_{\alpha,\alpha} \leq \|A\|_{\alpha,\alpha}\|B\|_{\alpha,\alpha}$

I do not understand the reason for this extra section for square matrices, is this not just a special case of what was written previously?

---

In addition, using this can we then say that for rectangular matrices $A$ and $B$. And for the spectral norm $\|\cdot\|_2$, i.e the induced norm from using the 2-norm for both vector spaces, that:

$\|AB\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2 \|B\|_2$

Comment: Note that the definition of submultiplicativity only makes sense if you have a normed space with a product, so this only works for square matrices.

Comment: @ronno Does this then mean that [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2599804/762889) is wrong? That the spectral norm is not in general sub-multiplicative for non-square matrices.

Comment: I wouldn't call that submultiplicative, but I guess there isn't a better name for this property. That answer seems correct since it specifies what it means by *submultiplicative*.

Comment: What? Could you please clarify your first comment then. Is what I have written wrong, if so which part exactly. Sorry im just a bit confused know.

Comment: Maybe you should write down your definition of the sub-multiplicative property. But the square matrix version of the inequality is in fact a special case of the more general version with three (a priori distinct) norms.