# An inequality in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a paper. There is an upper bound for largest singular value of matrix $A$. Suppose its largest singular value is $d$ and $d\leq p$. Now we have a row vector $U$. It is said that in the paper $\|UA\|\leq \|U\|p$ but really I don't understand it. Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using $2$-norm, then it has the sub-multiplicative property.

Hence $$\|UA\| \le \|U\|\|A\|=\|U\|d \le \|U\|p$$

Comment: Yes it is 2-norm. Why the first ineqaulity is true? What is definition of norm $A$?

Comment: refer to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). It is an induced norm. First we define the vector norm and use it to define a matrix norm as follows: $\|A\|_2 = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$. It is equal to the largest singular value. Refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/580838/306553) for a proof of submultipllicative property of the matrix norm.