# Prove a matrix function is continuous

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, matrix-decomposition

Suppose $f:(C[0,2],\lVert\rVert_{\infty})\to (M_{2}(\mathbb{R}), \lVert T\rVert_{op})$, where $\lVert T\rVert_{op} = \sup_{\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert =1}\lVert T\mathbf{x}\rVert$

Let $A=U^{-1}DU$ be some diagonalisable matrix, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries in $[0,2]$ and define $f(g)=g(A)=U^{-1}g(D)U$. (Note: $g(D)$ means apply the function $g$ to each entry of the matrix $D$). Prove that the function $f$ is continuous.

It seems I need need to use the epsilon-delta definition, but I do not know how to simplify the expression 
$$\lVert f(g)-f(h)\rVert_{op}=\sup_{\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert=1}\lVert U^{-1}[g(D)-h(D)]U\mathbf{x}\rVert$$ in order to relate it to $\lVert g-h\rVert_{\infty}$. How can I do this?

Comment: If I correctly understood your question. You need to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find $\delta>0$ so that for any two functions $h, g$ such that $\|h - g\|_\infty <\delta$ you have $\|f(h) - f(g)\|_{op} < \varepsilon$

Comment: What is $\lVert f(h)-f(g)\rVert$ explicitly?

Comment: $f(h)$ is an operator that operates on diagonalisable matrices, so you really need to write $f(h)[\cdot]$ where, when you apply   $f(h)[\cdot]$ instead of $\cdot$ you plug in a diagonalisable matrix. So I think $\mathbf{x}$ in the definition of $\|T\|_{op}$ is not a vector but a diagonalisable matrix. How is $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined?

Comment: Unfortunately there weren't many details... I think it's just the space of all 2x2 real matrices. I'm still very confused as to how to derive a useful expression for $||f(h)-f(g)||$. The question did give specific matrices for $A$, $U$ and $D$ though - but I thought the function shouldn't depend on those matrices (unless the diagonal matrix was something silly like the zero matrix), so I left them out.

Comment: Well, another possibility is that you assume that $A$ is fixed. In this case your definitions make sense. And then you really need to write $f_A$, to show that for each $A$ you get a different map. And then show that for any $A$, $f_A$ is a continuous map. In which case explicitly $\|f_A(h)- f_A(g)\|_{op}=\sup_{\| \mathbf{x}\|=1}\|\left(U^{-1} h(D) U - U^{-1} g(D) U\right) \mathbf{x}\|$

Comment: How do you simplify the expression on the RHS to be able to relate it to $||g-h||_{\infty}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not tell us which norm you use on $\mathbb R^2$. But since all all norms on $\mathbb R^2$ are equivalent, we may take $\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert = \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_\infty = \max(\lvert x_1 \rvert, \lvert x_2 \rvert)$.

Since the operator norm is submultiplicative (see e.g. [show operator norm submultiplicative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/435621)), we get

$$\lVert f(g) - f(h) \rVert_{op} = \lVert U^{-1}g(D) U  - U^{-1}h(D) U  \rVert_{op} = \lVert U^{-1}(g(D)  - h(D)) U  \rVert_{op} \\ \le \lVert U^{-1} \rVert_{op} \cdot \lVert g(D)  - h(D) \rVert_{op} \cdot \lVert U  \rVert_{op} = c \lVert g(D)  - h(D) \rVert_{op} =  c \lVert (g - h)(D) \rVert_{op} .$$
With $u = g - h$ we get
$$\lVert u(D) \rVert_{op} = \sup_{\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert=1}\lVert u(D)\mathbf{x} \rVert = \sup_{\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert=1}\lVert \begin{pmatrix}
u(d_{11})x_1\\
u(d_{22})x_2
\end{pmatrix} \rVert = \sup_{\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert=1}\max( \lvert u(d_{11})x_1 \rvert, \lvert u(d_{22})x_2 \rvert) \\ = \max( \lvert u(d_{11}) \rvert, \lvert u(d_{22}) \rvert) \le \sup_{t \in [0,2]} \lvert u(t) \rvert = \lVert u \rVert_\infty$$
which finishes the proof.