# Does Cauchy-Schwartz inequality work for matrix norms?

Tags: cauchy-schwarz-inequality, matrix-norms

This question has been answered.

[show-that-the-operator-norm-is-submultiplicative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435621/show-that-the-operator-norm-is-submultiplicative).

We all know that Cauchy-Schwartz inequality works for vector inner product. Also, it works for the matrix innner product. Specifically, the following is the relation between matrix inner product and matrix norms
$$\tag{1}
|<A,B>|^2\le\|A\|^2\|B\|^2
$$
when $A=cB$, the equality holds. The definition of inner product for matrices is
$$\tag{2}
<A,B>=\text{vec}(A)^H\text{vec}(B)=\text{tr}(A^HB) 
$$

If the LHS of (1) is replaced by induced matrix norms and matrix product, does the Cauchy Schwartz inequality still work, like the following induced $L_2$-norm(also known as, spectral norm)
$$\tag{3}
\|AB\|_2^2\le \|A\|_2^2 \|B\|_2^2
$$
where $\|A\|_2=\sup_{u\neq0}\frac{\|Au\|_2}{\|u\|_2}$. Since $\|A\|_2=\max\{\text{eig(A)}\}=\lambda_{\text{max}}(A)$, if (3) holds, it would imply the following inequality
$$\tag{4}
\lambda_{\text{max}}(AB)^2\le \lambda_{\text{max}}(A)^2\lambda_{\text{max}}(B)^2
$$

Comment: Please provide the definition of that norm, and some thoughts on why it might/might not work

Comment: This is not the CS inequality,  but the result holds.

Comment: This is known as **submultiplicativity**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those types of norms are called submultiplicative. Not every norm is submultiplicative, but every operator norm is.