# Example of operators which are strictly submultiplicative $\|ST\| \overset{!}{<}\|S\|\|T\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let us consider normed spaces $E, F$ and $G$ over some field $\mathbb K$ and operators $T\in L(E,F)$ and $S\in L(F,G)$. I know that $\|ST\| \leqslant \|S\|\|T\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435621/show-that-the-operator-norm-is-submultiplicative)).

What are examples of $S,T$ where the inequality is strict? $$\|ST\| \overset{!}{<}\|S\|\|T\|$$

I was thinking about setting where $E,F,G$ are $\mathbb R$ vector spaces and $S, T$ are matrices with real coefficients but I couldn't come up with an example.

Thank you.

Comment: Try finding some matrices whose product is the zero matrix, for example.

Comment: Or just one matrix whose square is $0.$

Comment: Can you please fix the link for the operator norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following linear transformations of the plane
$$
T: (x,y)\to (2x, y)
$$
And
$$
S: (x,y)\to (x,2y)
$$
So $T$ is a horizontal dilation, $S$ is a vertical one. Clearly $\|T\|=2$, $\|S\|=2$ and, if you apply them sequentially, $\|ST\|=2$ (homothety).

Answer (score 3):

An extreme case is $$S = T = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ where $\|S\| = \|T\| = 1$ but $\|ST\|=0$.

Comment: An extreme lazy version $\|S\|=\|T\|\neq 0$ as $S=T\neq 0.$ :)