Let $E = \mathbb{K}^d$ and $u,v \in L(E)$. Prove ${|||}u \circ v {|||} \leq \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert$
$\newcommand{\vertiii}[1]{{\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert #1 
    \right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert}}$
Fyi, $d\in \mathbb{N}$ and L(E) is the set of continuous linear maps from E to E. As far as I understand, $$\vertiii{u\circ v}= \sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\lVert (u\circ v)(x) \rVert}{\lVert x \rVert} = \sup_{\lVert x \rVert = 1}\lVert (u\circ v)(x) \rVert.$$
So far, I have that $\vertiii u= \sup_{y \neq 0}\frac{\lVert u(y) \rVert}{\lVert y \rVert}$ =  and we can set $y = v(x)$, but I dont know where to go from here. The correction is very brief and basic and I don't understand it at all. They just write:
$$ \lVert u\circ v \rVert \leq \vertiii{u} \lVert v(x) \rVert \leq \vertiii{u}\vertiii{v} \lVert x \rVert$$ and that the result follows from here... I suppose from here, we can just assume $x \neq 0$ and divide by $\lVert x \rVert$ then take the $\sup$ to obtain the triple norm (and that's how we obtain the desired inequality). However, I don't understand how we get the first inequality, and then the second one. If anyone could shed some light on this I'd be really grateful.
Thanks so much!
EDIT: nevermind I got it, I think.
Set $ x = \lVert x\rVert \cdot \hat{x}$. Then $u(x) = u(\lVert x\rVert \cdot \hat{x}) = \lVert x\rVert u(\hat{x})$. Then we can take the norm and find that $\lVert u(x) \rVert = \lVert x \rVert \lVert u(\hat{x}) \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert \sup_{\lVert \hat{x}\rVert \neq 0}\lVert u(\hat{x}) \rVert = \lVert x \rVert \cdot {|||}u{|||}$.
So we have $\lVert (u\circ v)(x)\rVert  = \lVert u(v(x)) \rVert \leq \lVert v(x) \rVert \cdot {|||} u {|||} \leq {|||}v{|||}\cdot {|||}u{|||}\cdot \lVert x \rVert$ and then we can divide by $\lVert x\rVert$ and take the supremum to get the triple norm inequality... I think this is right.
Also, I noticed this question got downvoted. Just for future reference, was this question not appropriate in the forums I tagged it to?

I don't know why you need a triple-vert, but I've fixed it for the body.  As it stands, your question is only in the title, where the code is still broken.  Move it to the body and rewrite the title.

Thank you for fixing the body. I fixed the title just now. Yeah I don't think we need the triple norm to prove it.

Perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435621/show-that-the-operator-norm-is-submultiplicative has what you're looking for

@rafilou2003 thank you so much! this is exactly it
